# How to Show/Hide some content in email content?

Tags: javascript, html, email, multilingual

I have to send a bilingual mail in which only one language content is visible at a time if English version is visible to user then french content should be hidden and when user click for french version english version content will hide and french version should be visible to user.
I read many articles around that and tried many things but **not** found anything helpful.

Comment: This is generally not possible (IMHO), because it would require JavaScript code to switch between language versions, and most mail clients prevent JS to run in HTML e-mail due to security.

Comment: Bilingual emails are usually sent with _both_ languages visible. Which one is higher is up to you, usually.

Comment: ok then if this is possible like table index  above both versions 1.English 2.French and when user click on French option it will take him to the portion where french mail starts.

Comment: As a receiver of this, I'd prefer to be able to select a language in my Subscriber Preferences, instead of being flooded with long mails containing 50% language that I can't understand.